# bulma: horizontal form controls not expanded correctly

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have one text input and 2 selects that I want to put them horizontally. based on bulma css framework, that what I'm supposed to do:

```
<div class="field is-horizontal">
  <div class="field-body">
     <div class="field">
        <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left">
           <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="id" id="id">
           <span class="icon is-small is-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        </p>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <p class="control">
           <span class="select">
              <select name="status" id="status">
                 <option value="">Status:</option>
                 <option value="active">active</option>
                 <option value="pause">pause</option>
              </select>
           </span>
        </p>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <p class="control">
           <span class="select">
              <select name="limit" id="limit">
                 <option value="">Limits:</option>
                 <option value="10">10</option>
                 <option value="20">20</option>
              </select>
           </span>
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

normally the last 2 selects should take their real width and the first input should expand until it takes the available space, but this is what i'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `is-narrow` to the fields you want to be narrow:

```
<div class="field is-narrow">
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/ut4nedq2/

Answer (score 6):

You need to combine `control is-expanded` with `select is-fullwidth`.

Here is an example:

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.2/css/bulma.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="field is-horizontal">
  <div class="field-body">
     <div class="field">
        <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left">
           <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="id" id="id">
           <span class="icon is-small is-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        </p>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <p class="control is-expanded">
           <span class="select is-fullwidth">
              <select name="status" id="status">
                 <option value="">Status:</option>
                 <option value="active">active</option>
                 <option value="pause">pause</option>
              </select>
           </span>
        </p>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <p class="control is-expanded">
           <span class="select is-fullwidth">
              <select name="limit" id="limit">
                 <option value="">Limits:</option>
                 <option value="10">10</option>
                 <option value="20">20</option>
              </select>
           </span>
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
```